# JAVASCRIPT Can someone fix my code?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me fix my code?
The function is like the Eval function but has a √ added but it doesn't work

```
function Eval(n) {
    var a = n.split("√").length - 1;
    var b = n.split("√").length;
    var c = a.replace("√" + d, e);
    var d = parseFloat(b[1]);
    var e = Math.sqrt(d);
    while (a != 0) {
        b();
        d();
        e();
        c();
        return;
    }
}
document.write(Eval("64+√68+32"));
```

Comment: you vars aren't functions, don't use ()

Comment: Uhh.. Please open the console of your browser, there's a bunch of error messages waiting for you.

Comment: while this while ? (o_o) ?

Comment: @Teemu I'm coding on android not on a computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code and going by your approach, I have updated the code to following. Please see, whether it helps!

Please note, I am assuming as per the name of the function, that you want to evaluate the expression. Also, there are other assumptions as well, like there will be only one square root expression and all operations will be additive.

```js
function Eval(n) {
  var b = n.split("√"); // you were expecting b to be an array      
  var a = b.length - 1; // you can use b here      
  var d = parseFloat(b[1]); // d should have been assigned before using in c
  var e = Math.sqrt(d);
  var c = n.replace("√" + d, e);
  return c.split("+").reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return a + parseFloat(b); // sum up all the values
  }, 0);
}
console.log(Eval("64+√68+32"));
```

You can try tweaking [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ntKj87Cttuxto6Ujj57?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. @nikhil. Hope i learn more.

Comment: @MMJM - I am sure you will :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function eval(n){
   var numbers = n.split('+'); // split the exepression with the + operator
   var result = 0; // initaliaze the result to 0
   for(number of numbers){ // for each number of numbers
       if(number.indexOf('√') !== -1){ // if the number contains sqrt
           number = +number.substring(1, number.length); // cast to int
           result += Math.sqrt(number);
       }else{
           number = +number; // cast string to int, NaN if not possible
           result += number;
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

This function will work for you additions.
Not that this is just a point to start, and not the best way of doing it, I tried to be the more comprehensive seeing that you are a beginner in javascript

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate your answer. @D. Peter

Comment: Hope this will be a good point to start